# Android Cusom Button Stretch Background

Tags: android

i am working custom button in android and i am set custom style and apply from back ground of button and my problem is image not stretch button background and i want to stretch background based on button size here' my custom button xml code:

**custom_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/disable" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

here's my layout xml code refer button style xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
```

here's my output below screen shot:

[image]

anyone can help me how to fix this issue with greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

use 9-patch images for selector images. this will help Android to stretch your images as you described in your 9-patch boundaries

[Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

[Draw 9-patch Tutorial](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial)

Another [Android 9 Patch Image Tutorial](http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the draw9patch application found in android-sdk/tools. Check instructions how it works and backgrounds should be able to scale properly.